# Android help, trying to get value moved from one class to another (android app)

Tags: java, android, class, transfer

I am trying to get a function and a int from Class B into Class A. Can someone please help me. I have been stuck here for multiple days now.

Class B
https://github.com/akballow/help-me-please/blob/master/nRFToolbox/src/no/nordicsemi/android/nrftoolbox/profile/BleProfileServiceReadyActivity.java

Class A
https://github.com/akballow/help-me-please/blob/master/nRFToolbox/src/no/nordicsemi/android/nrftoolbox/proximity/ProximityManager.java

What I want to do is call function getRssi() from class A, to be called inside function onRecive() in Class B where I put the code "mble.getRssi();" then get the int rssilevel from Class A to B.

Can somone please explain to me how I can accomplish this? I tried to "public PRoximityManager mble" inside class B, but it would ultimatly fail. I am so desperate that if someone can help me accomplish this I will send 5 bucks from paypal to you as a reward (only if that is legal, i dont want to get in trouble on here).

Thanks

Comment: How about making particular method static, will that not help?

Comment: could you please provide an example, also do you mean making rssilevel static? because I need rssilevel to change whenever getRssi is called from Class B.

Comment: if rssilevel is a global variable then you can make it static, what i meant is in calss A, make getRssi as static method, and from Class B simply access it by A.getRssi..

Comment: hold on, i guess I got it wrong, can you share code for this calss as well BleProfileService ??

Comment: you should be able to go back in directory to see them all. Thank you so much for taking time to help.

Comment: my goal is to be able to grab the RSSI level of a connected device whenever it sends a batterylevel value. Then I want to use the value and display the level as a value on the app, just a quick summary.

Comment: alright, hold tight let me see it through !!

Comment: Quick info, in probelm description you have mentioned calss A as BleProfileServiceReadyActivity, and have mentioned there is a method named getRssi in it, but after brwosing am not able to locate that method in that class, but instead this method is present in Calss B proximity manager, can you clarify you question again?

Comment: My mistake, I mixed up the links for class A and B, A is ProximityManager, and B is BleProfileServiceReadyActivity.

Comment: Class B funciton onReceive() runs function getRssi() from A, then takes rssilevel[this is generated after getRssi() runs] from Class A into Class B.

Comment: yep, check the answer poster by user3167555, thats your issue fix.

Comment: Can you please help again, the issue was not resolved, and the guy who posted answer did not reply.

Comment: What issue are you facing, did you try to implement his suggested change?

Comment: I keep getting nullexception error right when i get to the line getRssi

here is the error log.
http://pastebin.com/Wwp81JhH

also this messeage:
07-23 23:55:15.830: W/dalvikvm(31781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41811898)

Answer (score 2):

First you should edit your post because your links are backwards.  The getRssi() function is in the link that you have labeled as Class B, and the onRecive() function is in the code you linked as Class A....Or perhaps your wording is a little confusing.

Either way, if all you want to do is get an integer value from getRssi() then change the return type of getRssi() from void to int and specify the value you desire to be returned....for example

```
public int getRssi(int rssilevel)
{
    this.rssilevel = rssilevel;

    return rssilevel; 
}
```

Back in your class that calls the function, set the value of an int to the getRssi() function, and what even integer is returned will now be the value of your int

```
int x = mble.getRssi(some_int_argument);
```

Comment: mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi(); needs to be ran first before rssilevel can be returned. Could I put it inside the getRssi function?

Comment: I did everything you said, and i get erro "The method getRssi() in the type BleProfileService is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Comment: found issue, i had wrong class name for mble, i was able to compile but the app instantly crashes on phone when it gets to that line. any ideas, this is what i have been having problems with

Comment: Update your post with your new code and your error log please

you can put anything you need in the getRssi() function, as long as it returns an int as its final line of code.  Im not sure what is crashing your app, but if you have a value determined for rssilevel and you set an integer equal to the getRssi() function which should be returning your int, im guessing that would be rssilevel......then the app crashing may be related to something else

Please post your code

Comment: NullPointerException when ran

Comment: in your Log you should see a list of errors, look for the label that says "Caused By" and it should direct you to the class and line of code that causes the crash

Comment: updated the code to reflect what i have now. currently getting nullpointer exception when ran in android phone via usb.

Comment: sorry which log? I was using logcat.. I dont have another log

Comment: please help out, i feel like we are so close.

Comment: The console section will show you everything that takes place while your log is running, when it crashes you will see a lot of red text, signifying what has gone wrong.  Try to read through that and solve the problem, remember to look for the phrase "Caused By" and the IDE will tell you what line the error took place on

I cannot look at your code again right now but will come back to it when i can

Comment: Thanks for your helping, I will post error log for you

Comment: here is the error log

http://pastebin.com/Wwp81JhH

07-23 23:55:15.830: W/dalvikvm(31781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41811898)